# Execute (SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = barracuda) is not working in command

Tags: mysql, command-line

I'm just trying to update the `unicode` on my MySQL database using the command line.

Here is the query that I suppose to execute:

e.g. 1

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format = barracuda;
```

e.g. 2

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table = 1;
```

e.g. 3

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix = 'on';
```

But unfortunately I've got this error response.

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    26540397
Current database: db_1234

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I'm not familiar with this error. Can someone please help me in order to resolve this issue? Or is there another way that performs my objectives? By the way, I'm using MAC OS, and my current MySQL version is (5.6.41-84.1)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error you need the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege . SUPER it's a global permission which applies on all databases and should be grant as follows :

```
 GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO `user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

*Note*. I supposed the user you are using is `user@localhost` , change with the one you are using.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this command but the error should be this: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'usersample'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @JesperMartinez you need to use a user with grant option, if no you should ask the dba administrator to give the permission mentioned above